# Postgres SQL - How to create a dynamic date variable

Tags: postgresql, date, variables, dynamic

I want my query to have a dynamic date. The way it is written now, I would have to manually change the date every time. Please see the following as an example:

```
(select*
from table2
    where table2.begin_timestamp::date = '2015-04-01')as start
left outer join 
(Select *
from table 1
    where opened_at::date >= ('2015-04-01' - 15)
    and opened_at::date <= '2015-04-01’)
```

I don't want '2015-04-01' to be hard-coded. I want to run this query over and over for a series of dates.

Comment: How do you choose the date? Looks like you just want the last 15 calendar days.

Comment: Basically my query which is much bigger than this says: take date X from table 2 and give me all product purchases. Then from table 1 select all data within the last 15 days of the purchase date. At the end of the query I should be able to say one person purchased a car on 4/1/2015 (table 2) and within 15 days of making that purchase he test drove the car on 4 different days (table 1).   But I want to run this query for all dates within a given window of time (say the month of April) how do I make the date dynamic so I dont have to manually adjust the day everytime I run it

Comment: I am assuming I need to use some type of loop function but I am unsure how. -- any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Using normal joins, you can do this in an `on` clause or `where` clause but not *inside* the subquery.  That leads to logic like this:

```
from (select*
      from table2
     ) start left outer join 
    table 1
    on opened_at::date >= table2.begin_timestamp::date - interval '15 day' and
       opened_at::date <= table2.begin_timestamp::date
```

Comment: Hi Gordon - thanks for your answer but I am afraid it isn't that easy. This query is massive. I merely pulled together a quick snippet of what I was working with to help portray my question properly. -- I am afraid I need some type of loop. I wish I could create a date variable that would loop through a given date range. Then in my query, reference that variable wherever a date appears. Do you have any ideas on how to do this? I can't find anything online that addresses this issue. Your help is very much appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a postgres developer but I think you can adapt a technique from the sql server world called "tally tables".

Esentially your goal is to join day d and the window of days that are at most 15 days greater than it.

You can use something like

```
SELECT * FROM generate_series('2015-04-01'::timestamp,
                              '2015-04-30 00:00', '1 days');
```

To generate a date sequence and from there you can write something like

```
select *
from table a
join generate_series('2015-04-01'::timestamp,'2015-04-30','1 days') s(o)
  on a.begin_timestamp::date = s.o
join table2 b
  on a.opened_at>= b.begin_timestamp::date - interval '15 days' 
     and opened_at::date <= table2.begintimestamp::date
```

Essentially, instead of looping you use a series of the dates between the beginning of the interval and the end of the range to produce the results you are after.